# Issues with Android apps sharing same UID

Tags: android, security, ipc

I have three android apps: app_1, app_2 and app_3. All are signed with the same key and share the same UID. app_1 and app_3 don't have a persistent storage (no database + file system), they both work on app_2 user space. I have two questions here:

1. if app_2 dies or shutdown by the system, what will happen to its user space? Can app_1 and app_2 still access to it?
2. I need a way to notify app_2 when app_1 and app_3 are done with the persistence storage, then app_2 can take some measures. I am not sure if I run a service within app_2 with some event listeners will fit my need. Is there a guaranteed way to make app_2 into a sleep mode and wake-up during events? Any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your persistent storage in /data/data will remain intact even when the app is not running. It will only be wiped when you removed the app. Also don't hardcode your path because in 4.3 each user will have their own data path.
2. A broadcast listener will serve this purpose. Declare it in your manifest of app 2.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! Am aware that multi-user support has been introduced since 4.2. I still want keep shared data in a directory relative to app_2, i.e. /data/data/<app_2_packageName>/<shared_data_dir>. Will this a problem in 4.3? Does a broadcast listener requires app_2 to be in active state in order to get notification (I read somewhere about this, correct me if am wrong)?

Comment: What do you mean by active state? As in having a activity running in the foreground or a service running in the background? If so then no. If you declared your listener in the manifest it will be invoked (unless it is an ordered broadcast and some higher priority receiver canceled it)

Comment: After Honeycomb 3.1 or above, when an app is installed, it is in stopped state. When the application is first launched, it is moved out of stopped state, that's what i want to say with "active state".An app in stopped state won't get started by all broadcast intents. A user can put the app into stopped state manually but not sure if there is any scenario that the system changes an app into stopped state automatically.